# AutoMapper: Deep property mapping + converter

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a lot of autogenerated similar API models per endpoint (which I cannot change!) and like to map to a single destination.

An example would be if I like to map the [IDRCleanseMatch.json](https://directplus.documentation.dnb.com/assets/APIs/IDRCleanseMatch.json) and [cmpelkv2.json](https://directplus.documentation.dnb.com/assets/APIs/cmpelkv2.json) endpoints from the Dun&Bradstreet API:

```
Api1.Organization → OrganizationDestinationModel
Api2.Organization → OrganizationDestinationModel
```

Here are the source models and the destination model:

```cs
namespace Api1
{
    public class Organization 
    {
        public string Duns { get; set; }
        public DunsControlStatus DunsControlStatus { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryName { get; set; }
        //...
    }
    public class DunsControlStatus 
    {
        public OperatingStatus OperatingStatus { get; set; }
        //...
    }
    public class OperatingStatus 
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int? DnbCode { get; set; }
        //...
    }
}
namespace Api2 { /* Same as above. */ }
public class OrganizationDestinationModel
{
    public string Duns { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOutOfBusiness { get; set; }
}
```

My approach is to use the a generic helper method:

```cs
config.MapToOrganizationDestinationModel<Api1.Organization>();
config.MapToOrganizationDestinationModel<Api2.Organization>();

private static void MapToOrganizationDestinationModel<TSource>(this IMapperConfigurationExpression config)
{
    config
        .CreateMap<TSource, OrganizationDestinationModel>()
        .ForMember(
            destination => destination.Name,
            options => options.MapFrom(nameof(Api1.Organization.PrimaryName))
        )
        // Doesn't work!!!
        // ArgumentException : 'DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus.DnbCode' is not a member of type 'Core.Api1.Organization' (Parameter 'propertyOrFieldName')
        .ForMember(
            destination => destination.IsOutOfBusiness,
            options => options.ConvertUsing(
                new IsOutOfBusinessConverter(),
                $"{nameof(Api1.Organization.DunsControlStatus)}.{nameof(Api1.DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus)}.{nameof(Api1.OperatingStatus.DnbCode)}"
            )
        )
        ;
}
public class IsOutOfBusinessConverter : IValueConverter<int?, bool>
{
    public bool Convert(int? code, ResolutionContext _) => code == 403;
}
```

But I'm totally stuck with the following `IsOutOfBusiness` mapping! Is there any chance just to convert `int? → bool` and point to `Organization.DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus.DnbCode` as string to stick with my "non-typed" mapping.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be tested by others and shows how you want to use the automapper.

Comment: Can you please include the source (Api1.Organization) and destination (OrganizationDestinationModel) Models you are trying to Map?

Comment: You're welcome. I pushed all necessary code to run a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

It's like the method `ConvertUsing` don't accept navigation property scheme. Maybe you can use other `ForMember`'s overload with navigation property in lambda :

```cs
.ForMember(
    d => d.IsOutOfBusiness,
    opts => opts.MapFrom(s => (s.Organization.DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus.DnbCode ?? 0) == 403)
)
```

You can find other examples in the documentation : [Custom Value Resolvers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html)

In your case, the source type is unknown. You can use reflection to navigate to DnbCode :

```cs
private static void MapToOrganizationDestinationModel<TSource>(this IMapperConfigurationExpression config)
{
    config
        .CreateMap<TSource, OrganizationDestinationModel>()
        ...
        .ForMember(
            destination => destination.IsOutOfBusiness,
            opts => opts.MapFrom(org => (org.DnbCode() ?? 0) == 403)
        );
}

private static int? DnbCode(this object org)
{
    var dcs = org.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Api1.Organization.DunsControlStatus)).GetValue(org);
    var oss = dcs.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Api1.DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus)).GetValue(dcs);
    var dnb = oss.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Api1.OperatingStatus.DnbCode)).GetValue(oss);
    return dnb as int?;
}
```

Maybe more elegant way exists with AutoMapper, but I don't find...

Comment: This is no solution! I cannot write an `IMemberValueResolver<???, OrganizationDestinationModel, int?, bool>` which can be passed like this `.MapFrom<IsOutOfBusinessMemberValueResolver, int?>("DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus.DnbCode")`. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: This is the answer. `ConvertUsing` doesn't support that.

Comment: @Marcel, Indeed I miss the point that source type is unknown. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you like to use `ValueConverter` with `ConvertUsing` but you can achieve same result if you can modify your destination model (which I hope can be done) and without using `ValueConverter`:

Update the Destination Model by adding new property `DnbCode` and modify the `IsOutOfBusiness` as below

```
public class OrganizationDestinationModel
{
    public string Duns { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? DnbCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsOutOfBusiness { get { return (DnbCode ?? 0) == 403;  } }
}
```

Update `MapToOrganizationDestinationModel` method to map new property `DnbCode` as below

```
    public static void MapToOrganizationDestinationModel<T>(this IMapperConfigurationExpression config)
    {
        config
            .CreateMap<T, OrganizationDestinationModel>()
            .ForMember(
                destination => destination.Name,
                options => options.MapFrom(nameof(Api1.Organization.PrimaryName))
            )
            .ForMember(
                destination => destination.DnbCode,
                opts => opts.MapFrom("DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus.DnbCode")
            );
    }
```

Done.. You don't need mapping for `IsOutOfBusiness` property

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this solution:

```cs
private static void MapToOrganizationDestinationModel<TSource>(this IMapperConfigurationExpression config)
{
    //source
    var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "source");
    //source.DunsControlStatus
    var body = Expression.Property(source, nameof(Api1.Organization.DunsControlStatus));
    //source.DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus
    body = Expression.Property(body, nameof(Api1.DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus));
    //source.DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus.DnbCode
    body = Expression.Property(body, nameof(Api1.OperatingStatus.DnbCode));
    //source => source.DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus.DnbCode
    var dnbCodeSelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, int?>>(body, source);

    config
        .CreateMap<TSource, OrganizationDestinationModel>()
        .ForMember(
            destination => destination.Name,
            options => options.MapFrom(nameof(Api1.Organization.PrimaryName))
        )
        .ForMember(
            destination => destination.IsOutOfBusiness,
            options => options.MapFrom(
                new IsOutOfBusinessMemberValueResolver<TSource>(),
                dnbCodeSelector //source => source.DunsControlStatus.OperatingStatus.DnbCode
                )
        );
}
```

I admit the composition of the `dnbCodeSelector` is really ugly but it's the only way to leave the destination model as it is AND reduce the `ValueResolver` to a reusable "converter":

```cs
public class IsOutOfBusinessMemberValueResolver<TSource> : IMemberValueResolver<TSource, object, int?, bool>
{
    public bool Resolve(TSource source, object destination, int? sourceMember, bool destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return sourceMember == 403;
    }
}
```

Maybe AutoMapper could shortcut this solution in a future release?